# Where is attribute form widget saved

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, geopackage

When i create widgets for the attribute form in the properties of a layer:

[image] 
Is this stored in the geopackage layer or in the QGIS project file?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: sorry for describing the topic so unclear. i added a screenshot to shed some light on the issue, i hope it is more understandable now!

Comment: @sn1ks - Normally the widgets are saved in the project file. If you want to save certain widget properties to the geopackage layer, go to its layer properties, click the _Style_ button at the bottom, select `Save as Default` and then save it to `Datasource Database`.

Comment: @Joseph ah superb! thats exactly what i needed! if you put your comment into an answer i will accept it instantly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the widgets configuration are saved in the project file. If you want to save certain widget properties to the geopackage layer, go to its layer properties, click the *Style* button at the bottom, select `Save as Default` and then save it to `Datasource Database`.